# Editing an object property in an array of objects without referencing array while editing

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have an application using Angular with Ionic 3 and i have an array of questions. These questions can be edited if the user has made something wrong.

The case is when i click to edit any queston it kind of references that question in the array and any edit reflects immediately to the array that's showing in the `*ngFor`.

Let me explain a little more before showing some code:

I create a question and save it, showing the questions and answers in an `*ngFor` in a list where i can edit the question or delete it.

[image: After saving the first question]

After i click in "edit" i send the question data back to my form where i can edit. While editing the listing on the right side changes the answer while i'm editing. But when i click to cancel editing it stays the value i've changed, but i need to change ONLY if the user clicks to save again.

[image: Editing question]

Here's my HTML code:

```
<ion-row>
<ion-col col-12 col-md-6>

  <!-- THE FORM I'M USING TO CREATE AND EDIT -->
  <form novalidate [formGroup]="novaQuestaoMultipla">
    <ion-item no-lines>
      <ion-label stacked>
        Título
        <p text-right [ngClass]="{'green': novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').value.length <= 70, 'yellow': novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').value.length > 70 && novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').value.length <= 140, 'red': novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').value.length > 140 }">({{novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').value.length}}/160)</p>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-textarea rows="4" formControlName="titulo" maxlength="160" [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': !novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').valid && (novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').dirty || multiplaInvalida)}"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf="titulosQuestoesFiltradas.length > 0" class="titulos" text-center>
    </div>

    <p text-center class="texto-campo-invalido" *ngIf="!novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').valid && (novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').dirty || multiplaInvalida)">Inválido</p>
    <br />

    <ion-row class="campo-respostas">
      <ion-col text-right col-8>
        <h3>Opções de Respostas</h3>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-left col-4>
        <button ion-button round icon-only color="gold" [disabled]="quantidadeRespostasMultipla == 5" (click)="novaOpcao()">
          <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row *ngIf="quantidadeRespostasMultipla > 0">
      <ion-col text-left>
        <h3>Texto</h3>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col text-right>
        <h3>Correta</h3>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row *ngFor="let r of respostasMultipla; let i = index" class="resposta-multipla" align-items-end>
      <ion-col col-12 col-md-8>
        <ion-item no-lines>
          <ion-label stacked>
            <p text-right [ngClass]="{'green': r.texto.length <= 20, 'yellow': r.texto.length > 20 && r.texto.length <= 35, 'red': r.texto.length > 35 }">({{r.texto.length}}/40)</p>
          </ion-label>
          <ion-input type="text" maxlength="40" [(ngModel)]="r.texto" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6 col-md-2 text-center>
        <button ion-button color="danger" round (click)="excluirOpcao(i)">
          <ion-icon name="ios-trash-outline"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6 col-md-2>
        <ion-item no-lines>
          <ion-toggle (ionChange)="escolheuCorreta(r, index)" [(ngModel)]="r.correto" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></ion-toggle>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <br />

    <div text-center>
      <button ion-button round color="danger" *ngIf="hasEditQuestao" (click)="cancelarEdicao()">Cancelar edição</button>
      <button ion-button round (click)="salvarMultipla()">Salvar Questão</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</ion-col>

<!-- THE LISTING I SHOW MY QUESTIONS AND WHERE I CAN CLICK TO EDIT THEM-->
<ion-col col-12 col-md-6 >
  <ion-item *ngFor="let q of questoesEscolhidasExibicao; let i = index" text-wrap>
    <h2>{{q.titulo}}</h2>
    <p *ngFor="let r of q.respostas">{{r.texto}}</p>
    <button ion-button outline color="gold" item-end icon-only (click)="editarQuestao(q, i)">
      <ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button outline color="danger" item-end icon-only (click)="removerQuestao(q, i)">
      <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
```

And here's my JS code for editing:

```
// EDIT QUESTION
editarQuestao(questao, index) {
    // HERE I TRY SAVING THE QUESTION IN ANOTHER VARIABLE SO IT CAN "LOSE" THE REFERENCE, BUT NO LUCK
    const respostas = questao.respostas;

    // SAVE THE QUESTION ID THAT'S THE OBJECT KEY
    this.hasEditQuestao = questao.id;
    // THE ARRAY INDEX WHERE THE QUESTION IS SAVED
    this.editQuestaoIndex = index;
    // THE QUESTION DATA
    this.questData = questao;

    // UPDATE THE FORM WITH THE QUESTION DATA
    this.novaQuestaoMultipla.get('titulo').setValue(questao.titulo);
    //this.novaQuestaoMultipla.get('tempo').setValue(10);
    this.respostasMultipla = respostas;
    this.quantidadeRespostasMultipla = this.respostasMultipla.length;
}
```

FIY i have an object and an array of objects. The object i'm using so i can simply push data only one time to Firebase. The array i use for showing purpouses.

How can i achieve this? How can i edit my question WITHOUT automatically changing it so i can update it ONLY when i click save? How can i remove that reference from my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have these issues due to `2-way data-bind` with `[(ngModel)]`.You can easily avoid these issues if you use [**Reactive forms**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

> Angular reactive forms facilitate a reactive style of programming that
>   favors explicit management of the data flowing between a non-UI data
>   model (typically retrieved from a server) and a UI-oriented form model
>   that retains the states and values of the HTML controls on screen.
>   Reactive forms offer the ease of using reactive patterns, testing, and
>   validation.
>
> You create and manipulate form control objects directly in the
>   component class. As the component class has immediate access to both
>   the data model and the form control structure, you can push data model
>   values into the form controls and pull user-changed values back out.
>   The component can observe changes in form control state and react to
>   those changes

Comment: Okay i'll try changing it to reactive form. Isn't there a known way to achieve this without changing to reactive form? Maybe some attribute i can use.

Comment: No, there is no such attribute.I'm pretty much sure reactive form is the solution here.Since it has all the control which you need to have on your UI and data model.

Comment: Yes changing it to reactive forms really helped, was just checking if there wasn't another option. Thanks man.